# chown -R $USER not working on my MATLAB folder in /Documents/

Tags: permissions, matlab

I'm lost. I just want to set the owner to MATLAB/* and all its subfolders to be davidv7. This is what I tried. How does it not work? It removed the lock on the MATLAB folder, but going further into the subfolders all the files still have locks on them which is why I'm guessing Matlab won't start.

[image: screen-shot]

Comment: Run it with the `-Rv` flag, this way you get an output if something has changed or not and do `davidv7:davidv7` instead of just `davidv7` to set the group too.

Comment: If it doesn't help, show the output of `ls -l` applied to one of files with a "lock".

Comment: since I'm guessing in my above comment it would be nice to report your outcome and if this fixed it for you so I know if to write an answer or not.

Comment: There was some output, like the terminal was looping through stuff and saying it changed owners, but the locks remained on the files if I went deeper, like matlab/bin/*

Comment: @Videonauth the program started, even though the locks were. No idea what went wrong. Could you explain what the difference between -Rv and -R is ?

Comment: `-R` means recursive, and `-v` means to verbose all actions, I just concatenated to flags into one `-Rv`. And if you mean in GUI nautilus it shows you still locks try pressing F5 for refreshing the window just to make sure it is actually showing what present state. My guess is that it was not starting because it might still have been owned by the root group.